# Visual Studio 2019 continues to look for a csproj in wrong path

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I've been working on a local repo on a WPF application. I've done after 1 week a get latest version (since a colleague of mine has implemented some feature I need to use) and I resolved conflicts as I've always done.

Now I've got issue loading the WPF project. It looks for a file inside another project folder

[image]

I've checked my .sln and .csproj files but it doesn't seem to have any pointers to WPF.core folder... does VS caches some data around?

Thanks

Comment: Define: "local repo" - are you using `git`, TFS, or SVN or something else? What's inside your `*.sln` file? Have you cleared your `.user` and `.suo` files?

Comment: I've found no .user and .suo files, where are those file usually located?

Comment: VS2017 (and possibly VS2015, I forget) moved many of those files to a hidden subdirectory named `.vs` located in the same directory as the `*.sln` file. I note that the `.vs` directory should not be included in source-control because it contains settings specific to your user-account and/or computer. If you're using `git` ensure your `.gitignore` file contains the right entries for Visual Studio and C# projects. Microsoft has a `.gitignore` template for VS files available: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore